# laravel spatie/media library serving images from s3 with cloudfront

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, laravel-medialibrary

I tried to integrate spatie media library with S3 and cloudfront. But I couldn't get the images to serve through cloudfront cdn.

Basically what I did was to set the `AWS_URL` to the Cloudfront url but when I check the image url it doesn't have the cloudfront in the url but rather the s3 and region.

Is it because I'm doing something wrong or is it because the package doesn't support this cdn?

Comment: As there are no code examples, possibly this comment helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39392114/laravel-and-aws-cloudfront#comment91621067_47890871

Comment: It only supports up to 5.5

Comment: You are sure? https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem#file-urls

Answer (score 2):

Taken from this [Github issue](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/issues/1756) you can set your s3 disk url to your CF url:

```
 's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_S3_CLOUDFRONT'),
 ],
```